# My eclipse window zoom in shortcuts do not respond in windows? Shortcuts are set up, but no response, how do?

Tags: java

My eclipse window zoom in shortcuts do not respond in windows? Shortcuts are set up, but no response, how do?
[image]

It is not the problem
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you are for sure using the wrong keys...

your keyboard has a num pad like this:[image]

and there the  **+** key is called ***Numpad_Add***

while the one on the alphabetic part is the ***+***
[image]